# Importing jodconverter on the old version will cause Application run failed error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, jodconverter

Importing **jodconverter** on the old version will cause Application run failed error

How can I fix it on the old version

The error comes from a version **before 7.0.0**
Reproduce, for example:
`7.0.0-bate-0、7.0.0-beat-1、6.10.5、6.10.1`

build.gradle add implementation:

```
implementation 'org.jodconverter:jodconverter-core:4.4.2'
implementation 'org.jodconverter:jodconverter-remote:4.4.2'
```

Exception：

```
17:21:59.441 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/my-micro-services/jh-7.0.0-beta1/build/classes/java/main/, file:/home/user/IdeaProjects/my-micro-services/jh-7.0.0-beta1/build/resources/main/]
17:21:59.456 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate factory class [org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor] for factory type [org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor]
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:168)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:104)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.loadPostProcessors(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:212)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.JhipsterApp.main(JhipsterApp.java:69)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2553)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:164)
    ... 30 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your question lacks some clarity and mentioning JHipster version does not help because JHipster is not involved. It's probably an incompatibility with Spring Boot version, you should compare versions between the one that work and the one that does not using gradle build scans https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:debugging-build-scans

Comment: But I use a separate springboot version and he can run normally，I don't know what went wrong

Comment: As I said, you have a separate app that works and a JHipster app that does not work, check all differences in dependency versions from the gradle build scan output https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html#sec:listing_dependencies Your error is a NoSuchMethodException so it's clearly a dependency incompatibility, you must find which jar and which version is the cause,then you will be able to fix it by yourself or you will report it to jodconverter project.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and see